# Passing value to each model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Can you explain to me the difference about 2 of this. Because I have problem when I want to pass values to models from some models but it can't generate an ID.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateShortcut([FromBody]ShortcutModel shortcut)
{
    var service = new DocumentService();
    FolderModel folders = new FolderModel
    {
        Title = shortcut.Title,
        ParentID = shortcut.ParentID,
        HeaderTitle = shortcut.HeaderTitle,
        HeaderReferenceNo = shortcut.HeaderReferenceNo,
        ItemType = shortcut.type,
        idreference = shortcut.idreference,
        ReferenceNo = shortcut.ReferenceNo
    };
    FolderModel newFolder = service.AddFolder(folders);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, newFolder);
}
```

But when I'm using this it works and want to generate ID:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Post(FolderModel folder)
{
    var service = new DocumentService();
    FolderModel newFolder = service.AddFolder(folder);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, newFolder);   
}
```

Comment: What's the value of ID you are getting right now? Which ID you want to generate?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya script one ID is null but 2nd script generate automaticly uniqueID via share point.

Comment: same request different output

Comment: check if `Post(FolderModel` passes the ID from client side itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post the codes of Models and service.AddFolder().

```
class FolderModel{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
     
    ...
}
```

Normally, it will [generate ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations) automatically after insert to DB.

> Screenshots of test

[image]

> Codes of controller

```
    [Route("/addfolder")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateShortcut([FromBody] ShortcutModel shortcut)
    {
        //var service = new DocumentService();
        FolderModel folders = new FolderModel
        {
            Title = shortcut.Title,
            ParentID = shortcut.ParentID,
            HeaderTitle = shortcut.HeaderTitle,
            HeaderReferenceNo = shortcut.HeaderReferenceNo,
            ItemType = shortcut.type,
            idreference = shortcut.idreference,
            ReferenceNo = shortcut.ReferenceNo
        };
        service.Folders.Add(folders);

        service.SaveChanges();

        int ID = folders.ID;
        //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, newFolder);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

> Body of Post

```
{
   "Title":"1",
   "ParentID":"2",
   "HeaderTitle":"3",
   "HeaderReferenceNo":"4",
   "type":"5",
   "idreference":"6",
   "ReferenceNo":"7"
}
```